# MPMoviePlayerController want video only, no audio

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I'm using video in my app for some tutorials screens. The video has no audio track. I have everything working except if the user is listening to audio already, like from the Music app, the audio is stopped when one of the tutorial videos starts.

Is there a way to only play the video and not affect the audio so the user can continue to enjoy the audio they had playing?

I tried setting `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];` before `[self.player play]` but that didn't work. `useApplicationAudioSession` looked promising but it was deprecated in iOS 6. I've also tried `AVPlayer` and again setting `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` before `play` but no luck.

Comment: Try to set `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`and try `AVPlayer` with `AVPreviewLayer` to play video. Hope this helps.

Comment: `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];` in the App Delegate worked, even with `MPMoviePlayerController`! Strange that it doesn't work when called right before `play`. If you wanna make this an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you should change audio session category before you initialise the movie player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`and try `AVPlayer` with `AVPreviewLayer` to play video. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're asking, but I'd written my answer before I re-read the question, and it might be useful for someone looking here…

---

You can't silence the audio on an `MPMoviePlayerController`. You can switch to using `AVPlayer` however, and remove the audio as follows:

```
// Load the video asset
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: <your-video-URL> options:nil];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

// Mute all the audio tracks
NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

// Create a player item
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[playerItem setAudioMix:audioZeroMix]; // Mute the player item

 // Create an AVPlayer
 AVPlayer * moviePlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem: playerItem]
```

Then you'll need to add the `AVPlayer`'s `playerLayer` to your view controller's view hierarchy.

The `AVPlayer` also gives you greater control over playback (finer grained seeking, for example).

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? How can I improve the answer?

Comment: Hi, the downvote is mine. I clicked the down arrow by mistake and now I can't remove it unless you edit the answer: `You last voted on this answer Jun 6 at 18:32. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.`

Answer (score -3):

```
[videoPlayer moviePlayer].useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.0];
```

Comment: useApplicationAudioSession is deprecated